# It is impossible to hide implementation of templates (for protection of intellectual property) from outside eyes. Am I right?

Tags: c++, templates

I have read the [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) and [Why can’t I separate the definition of my templates class from its declaration and put it inside a .cpp file?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl)

If I create the templates then I am to provide access also to their `cpp`-files additionally to their `h`-files, or write the definitions directly in the header file.

Therefore, if I want to allow to use fully my templates in other applications, then I can't hide their implementation from outside eyes (*for protection of intellectual property*). Am I right?

Comment: Should your templates be usable with user types, or is it ok to restrict them to a small predefined list of types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general you're right... the implementation must be exposed.

If your client only needs to instantiate them for a finite set of specific types that they can list for you, you can provide them with a pre-compiled object/library containing the implementations of the instantiations for just those types: see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl

Obfuscation is another possibility - let them see the code, but make it confusing and unmaintainable.

If neither of those options suit, consider whether you can provide a templated adapter that creates a run-time polymorphic interface over their user-provided type, capturing the specific set of functions your algorithms need.  Accept those adapters as a front-end to your code.  This does have runtime costs.

Answer (score 2):

Intellectual property is mostly protected by legal means, not technical ones.

<sup>(e.g. the technical possibility to read some header files do not give me the right to use it, or to copy its code elsewhere)</sup>

However, you might consider [code obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29) techniques. You might even customize your recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) for that purpose, i.e. write your [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) free software extension. It could mean weeks (or months) of work.

Alternatively, consider publishing your header-only template C++ library as [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)... (perhaps with GPL license).

But [IANAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL). You should ask your lawyer.